# Why do we have $X/G\cong \coprod_jX_j/G_j$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I'm reading Lei Fu's "Etale Cohomology Theory".

> Corollary 3.2.6. Let $S$ be a noetherian scheme,let $X\to S$ be an etale covering space, and let $G$ be a finite group acting on the right of $X$ such that $X\to S$ is invariant under $G$. Then the action is admissible and the quotient $X/G$ is an etale covering space of $S$.

> Proof. By 3.1.3 (ii), the action is admissible. $G$ acts on connected components of $X$. Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be connected components of $X$ so that any connected component of $X$ is of the form $gX_j$ for some $g\in G$ and a unique $j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Let $G_j=\{g\in G|gX_j=X_j\}$ be the stabilizer of $X_j$. Then we have $X/G\cong \coprod_jX_j/G_j\cdots$

Why do we have $X/G\cong \coprod_jX_j/G_j$?

Comment: You can think of the quotient as happening in two steps. First, each $X_i$ gets identified with each $gX_i$, so that the quotient map factors through a space $Y$ which has $n$ connected components, each corresponding to one of the $X_i$. The inherited $G$-action on $Y$ stabilizes each connected component, and quotienting by this action we get the result.